# Best Practices for UI design on Android (Usability/UX)

Tags: interaction-design, gui-design, android, usability

I'm switching for web development to Android development. I know some things about web usability and I see that UX is too often left behind on Android from my I experience with it.

As the interaction paradigms are pretty different from the web, I'm looking for resources about Android UI guidelines/best practices.

Could you give me some pointers here?

Comment: See this question for some more on the topic: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/what-key-things-form-the-best-android-app-ui

Comment: Google has since released official design documentation: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

- [Offical Google Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)
- [10 Tips For Android UI Design](http://phandroid.com/2011/05/11/10-tips-for-android-ui-design/)
- [Android UI Design Tips](http://www.slideshare.net/AndroidDev/android-ui-design-tips)
- [Designing For Android](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/30/designing-for-android/)
- [Android User Interface Design](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/series/android-user-interface-design/)
- [Android App Developers GUI Kits, Icons, Fonts and Tools](http://speckyboy.com/2010/05/10/android-app-developers-gui-kits-icons-fonts-and-tools/)
- [Trending Android UI anti-patterns](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2011/07/trending-android-ui-anti-patterns.html)
- [Google I/O 2010 - Android UI design patterns](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M1ZBjlCRfz0) - In this session, the Android User Experience team will show the types of patterns you can use to build a great Android application
- [Android UI Design Patterns & Best Practices](http://www.slideshare.net/mswolfson/android-ui-patterns)
- [User Interface Guidelines - Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)
- [Android OS Research](http://pshyama.wordpress.com/2011/07/05/android-os-research/)

Comment: Could you add some information to each link to indicate what's being offered?

Answer (score 13):

Google launched [Android Design](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) which provides design guidelines to achieve a consistent style across the platform. It includes information about:

- **General principles** such as consistency ("If it looks the same, it should act the same") or use of unobtrusive notifications ("Only interrupt me if it's important").
- **Layout and visual style** including icon design, typography (Roboto typeface), color scheme, themes, considerations for multiple screen sizes and densities.
- **Interaction patterns and specific widgets** to support them. You can find design guidelines to resolve common problems (navigation, user notification, etc.) and widgets the platform offers (buttons, lists, text fields, etc.) with recommendations for their use. I have included below an image used to illustrate the design of notifications:

[image: Parts of a notification]

Comment: The following excerpt from those guidelines had me laughing though:
_When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of the current screen, pressing the Back key will have the same result as pressing an Up button -- this is a common occurrence. However, unlike the Up button, which ensures the user remains within your app, the Back key can return the user to the Home screen, or even to a different application._

(from the "Back vs. Up" section in the Patterns chapter, Navigation page)

Answer (score 4):

Motorola have a good page on [Best Practices for User Interfaces](http://developer.motorola.com/docstools/library/Best_Practices_for_User_Interfaces/) with some videos. I think it's a great place to start.

To summarize each section title here (copied from the page above):

1. Read the [UI guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html)
2. Understand and design for [touch mode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2008/12/touch-mode.html)
3. But, support multiple interaction modes
4. Use notifications and the window shade
5. Support interaction between applications
6. Keep your UI fast and responsive (see Google I/O talk: [Writing zippy Android apps](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4znvD-7VDA))
7. Use widgets and live folders
8. Handle screen orientation changes
9. Use images wisely
10. Use layouts that adapt to multiple devices

Comment: Moto link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

http://androidpatterns.com is a nice resource as well, but beware of some inconsistencies and less accurate information,  not to be used as a solo reference.

Answer (score 2):

I just stumbled over a [Android Design Site](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) where design principles of Android 4.0 are shown, quite similar to Apple and Microsofts Guidelines. So for archive purposes this post.